# using a few data columns to plot chart and some to show on tooltip highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I want to plot an line graph using the columns 'date', 'value1', 'value2' and 'value3'. I don't want to include topics1, topics2 and topics3 on my chart while plotting, but when I click on the line, the respective topic should pop-up. Here is my data table [My data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmSDt.png)
This is the sample data file and it has thousands of such rows and this is an external csv file.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `seriesMapping` option and create custom property for each point - for example `topic`. Then, you will be able to use a reference to that property in tooltip:

```
data: {
    ...,
    seriesMapping: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 1,
        topic: 2
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 3,
        topic: 4
    }, {
        x: 0,
        y: 5,
        topic: 6
    }]
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b> topic: <b>{point.topic}</b><br/>'
}
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/56kqb2nv/

Comment: Thank you very much. Perfect answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd browse to https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic. I'd then take the example solution as a jsfiddle (button down there) and change the sample data. I would be testing and modifing it as long as I'd have the right solution for me.

The solution above gives you an example of a linear data set, so you've got a data point for each date. Therefore only the starting date was given: 2010. That could be hard for you to implement, because you only know the dates after reading the csv.

Therefore, I've modified the code above and now you can add non-linear data into it. See https://jsfiddle.net/b5kw308c/.

I've added:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
```

And the data blocks are different now:

```
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2010, 1, 1), 29.9],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 1, 2), 30.5],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 1, 3), 34.4],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 6), 40.2],
        [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 7), 46.0],
        [Date.UTC(2011, 1, 8), 60.0]
    ]
```

For the csv: you'll need a small javascript that reads the csv and creates arrays for the columns. These must exactly be like those needed by highcharts, see "series" in these examples.